# go to next row when a column contain certain value (sql server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is an example of the table that i'm working with (24hour system)

```
|ID      |Name        |Department  |InOutID|Date      | Hours | Minutes|
________________________________________________________________________
0123     | Phil Jones | security   |1      |2018-07-07| 7      |30      
________________________________________________________________________
0123     | Phil Jones | security   |2      |2018-07-07| 10     |30      
_________________________________________________________________________
0123     | Phil Jones | security   |1      |2018-07-07| 13     |30 
_________________________________________________________________________
0123     | Phil Jones | security   |2      |2018-07-07| 17     |00
```

i'm working with a scoring system database so basically what i need to do is verify the `IdInOut` column if it has 1 then its an entry if its 2 then its a exit and i should calculate the real amount of time that the epmloyee has spent in the office( the table is ordered by Date,Hours,Minutes desc) normally IdInOUt should be like this

```
    |IDInOut|
    _________
    2
    _________
    1
    _________
    2
    _________
    1  
    .....
```

basically what i need to do is set a cursor pointing at the first row and another cursor pointing  at the second row and for every iteration i subsrtact hours and minutes of the second cursor from the first cursor and store them into a variable then use it afterward
SO FAR SO GOOD but there is a problem with this previous table it's the following:

```
 |ID      |Name        |Department  |InOutID|Date      | Hours | Minutes|
   ________________________________________________________________________
   0123     | Phil Jones | security   |1      |2018-07-07|7      |30      
   ________________________________________________________________________
   0123     | Phil Jones | security   |1      |2018-07-07|7      |32     
   _________________________________________________________________________
   0123     | Phil Jones | security   |2      |2018-07-07|10     |30      
   _________________________________________________________________________
   0123     | Phil Jones | security   |1      |2018-07-07|13     |30 
   _________________________________________________________________________
   0123     | Phil Jones | security   |2      |2018-07-07|17     |00
```

there are successive rows with the same IdInOut which represents a problem since my method of work is that with every iteration i mentioned previously every cursor jumps with 2 row but when this case occurs every cursor should jump with only one row in which case i didn't find the solution :/ 
 i Know the explanation is pretty long but i'm really stuck here 
any help is welcomed

Comment: A `CURSOR` would be an awfully slow way to do this. Are you really still using SQL Server 2008 (it's got less than a year's (extended) support left now)? A Windows Function would make this much easier; otherwise you'll need to use some `JOIN`s. A `CURSOR` is rarely the right choice for creating a dataset; it's normally only good for iterative tasks (such as sending data derived emails to different recipients).

Comment: When there is two or more records of the same type after one another, if sorted by time, which one would you like to use for your calculations?

Comment: @jeffery . . . You explain the problem, but you don't explain the solution you want.  What result set are you looking for?

Comment: @Larnu  so how should i proceed ?

Comment: @stickybit the second one because in the first one he didn't really enter the office

Comment: @GordonLinoff when two successive row have the same InOutId i should be able to skip the first row and consider the second as the official time of entering if we're talking about the example i mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively efficient way to determine if the data is correct -- well almost.  It will determine if there are missing "1"s or "2"s in the data.  This version does not determine if the first id is "1", because your question does not mention that.

The best solution is to use `lag()` and `lead()`.  However, SQL Server 2008 doesn't support these functions.  So, let's approach this as a gap-and-islands.  Are there any situations with more than 1 "1" or "2" in a row for a given `id`?  The following code should find these anomalies:

```
select id, inoutid, count(*) as num_in_row,
from (select t.*,
             row_umber() over (partition by id, inoutid order by date, hours, minute) as seqnum_ii,
             row_umber() over (partition by id order by date, hours, minute) as seqnum_i
      from t
     ) t
group by id, inoutid, (seqnum_i - seqnum_ii)
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Actually this table doesn't exist in the first place i only created it but i didn't fill it yet here is the bit of code i tried to use but it didn't work

Comment: 'declare cursor c_pointage is select * from pointage;
v_pointage c_pointage%ROWTYPE;
v_date nvarchar;
v_heures int ; 
v_minutes int ; 
open c_pointage ;

Comment: begin 
for v_pointage in c_pointage loop 
v_date := CONVERT(varchar(10), v_pointage.DateHeureArrivee, 120);
v_heures := DATEPART(hour, v_pointage.DateHeureArrivee);
v_minutes :=  := DATEPART(minute, v_pointage.DateHeureArrivee);
insert into Calc_pointage values ( v_pointage.ID, v_pointage.Nom, v_pointage.Departement, v_pointage.NumCarte, v_pointage.IDterminale, v_pointage.NomTerminale, v_pointage.IDInOut,v_date,v_heures,v_minutes);
end loop;
end ;'

Comment: @jeffery . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  If you have another question, then ask a *question*, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: i ' m kinda new to how all this work , i'll post it ASAP