# what's wrong with this bit of code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, plsql

```
  declare 
cursor c_pointage is select * from pointage;
v_pointage c_pointage%rowtype;
v_date nvarchar;
v_heures int ; 
v_minutes int ; 
begin 
for v_pointage in c_pointage loop 
v_date:= CONVERT(varchar(10), v_pointage.DateHeureArrivee, 120) ;
v_heures := DATEPART(hour, v_pointage.DateHeureArrivee);
v_minutes := DATEPART(minute, v_pointage.DateHeureArrivee);
insert into Calc_pointage values ( v_pointage.ID, v_pointage.Nom, v_pointage.Departement, v_pointage.NumCarte, v_pointage.IDterminale, v_pointage.NomTerminale, v_pointage.IDInOut,v_date,v_heures,v_minutes);
end loop;
end ;
```

i keep getting these errors :

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'cursor'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3

Incorrect syntax near 'v_pointage'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13

Incorrect syntax near 'loop'.

ps : the data type from the table i'm inserting from match the one i'm inserting into

Comment: Doesn't really look like Transact-SQL, more like Oracle dialect. You can't use this in MS SQL Server as is, you will need to rewrite it.

Comment: tags plsql or tsql?

Comment: You can't run PL/SQL scripts in SQL Server and expect them to work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, the tag `plsql` shouldn't exist.

Comment: i studied PL/Sql theoretically i didn't practice it with a pc now i'm looking to implement  the script with ms sql server

Comment: This is pretty bad PL/SQL too - you don't need a *cursor* to insert the results of a query into a table. An `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` would be simpler and a LOT faster. It would probably work on both databases with minimal changes too

Comment: @jeffery that query is bad SQL, bad PL/SQL. Don't use it with either database. Use `INSERT ... SELECT`. For 100K rows it will be 50K times faster. SQL is a set-based language. You *don't* need loops and cursors, except in very rare and advanced situations like batch deletes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when should i use cursor ?

Comment: @jeffery probably never. Definitely not for the first 2-3 years, unless you encounter a case where you have to delete 5M rows out of a 20M row table. I'll repeat it, SQL is a *set-based language*. That means it's writtent to make queries *fast*, especially when you use indexes and row-by-row access is slow.

Comment: @jeffery - you should use a cursor generally as a last resort, and when you *have* to apply some form of processing that cannot work with sets. Such situations should be rare.

Comment: @jeffery when the database sees a query it will use indexes and statistics to create the best possible execution plan, process and buffer rows in bulk, use indexes to limit the data it reads, match it with other tables, lock only what's needed etc. When you use cursors though you force it to use the worst possible plan - read one row, write one row, read one row, write etc... while keeping locks an all rows until the cursor finishes. That's why cursors typically are N times slower *at least*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but the next step i'm going to do is calculate the hour spent in work and put them into another table that's probably data processing , so how can i do it without a cursor ?

Comment: But that's probably because you're still thinking about how *you* would write code in some other language to do things *row by (agonizing) row*. That's *not* the best way of solving problems in SQL. It's a declarative language where you tell it *what to do*, not *how to do it*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  sorry but as of my level of knowledge now, i can't think of another way to do it especially when there are conditions whether data should modified or not

Comment: @jeffery - yes, and you're going to learn - probably by asking more questions here :-) Everyone's a beginner at some point. Just realise that transitioning from procedural to declarative is likely to be a bit steeper that transitioning between two procedural languages, if you've had experience of doing that. You can write procedural code in SQL, but it's usually the last resort.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be writing a *cursor* for this at all. `INSERT ... SELECT` should do the job:

```
insert into Calc_pointage (/*TODO - Column list */)
select
    ID, Nom, Departement, NumCarte, IDterminale, NomTerminale, IDInOut,
    CONVERT(varchar(10), DateHeureArrivee, 120), --Ideally, CONVERT(date,DateHeureArrivee) instead
    DATEPART(hour, DateHeureArrivee),
    DATEPART(minute, DateHeureArrivee)
FROM pointage
```

But now I look at this, this also smells distinctively of your having decided to break a process down into a series of *procedural* steps (why are you just *copying* one table into another?) when the whole thing should probably just be a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as part of a *single* set-based query.

---

A key thing to get your head aroung when transitioning to writing SQL is to "think in sets". Try *not* to break the problem down, or at least, don't break it down into *loops* and how to process a *single row at a time*. If your input data doesn't resemble what you want, think about *how to transform* the entire set of rows into a set of rows that more closely resembles what you're looking for. Then write a CTE that does that transformation, and build from there.

Comment: From looking at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419900/go-to-next-row-when-a-column-contain-certain-value-sql-server-2008), it's as I suspected. Rather than `insert ... select`, this should just be used as a CTE (link added to answer if you're unsure of what that is)

Comment: I'd recommend against the storing the date as a `varchar`. It's going to cause way more trouble that it *might* solve.

Comment: @Larnu - agreed, added comment indicating the preferred conversion

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm still a newbie here i'll read more about what you referred to in your answer and THANKS